# Does using "limit" on Query consume read capacity on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Let's say I have a SortKey of "TimeUpdated". If I wanted to get the latest update with a Query for "LT" with UtcNow plus the PartitionKey with a Limit = 1, Do I expect read capacity to be counted towards only one item?

Comment: If you limit it to 1 then only 1 item will be read, so you will only "pay" for that 1 item. I have no idea what you mean by "LT", but if you want to get the "latest" item by the `TimeUpdated` sort key, then you need to set `ScanIndexForward` to false to get the latest item based on the sort key.

Comment: sorry LT means "LessThan" in that context. Thanks, if you post this as an answer I'll accept that.

Comment: Is it also true that if a KeyConditionExpression matches 100 items (each item is of 4KB), and Query Limit set 1, Now will it consume 1 RCU or 100 RCU ? – 
Shankar S
 30 secs ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you use a `KeyConditionExpression` in the way you describe (and **not** use `FilterExpression`), then indeed you pay only for the item you retrieve.

However, note that as usual in DynamoDB's RCU calculation, the item size is rounded up to 4KB. So even if you read a single 100 byte item, you will still pay for a full 4KB.

Comment: Is it also true that if a KeyConditionExpression matches 100 items (each item is of 4KB), and  Query Limit set 1, Now will it consume 1 RCU or 100 RCU ?